# React JS inheritance please give me advice

Tags: reactjs, inheritance

I am new in React JS and I develop some apps using React JS. And I need to use inheritance because I think this is better then rewrite a same code in JSX's. I write the code like this :

base class :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class GFormEdit extends Component {
    
    showModalList = () => {
        console.log('show modal list runs')
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>GFormEdit</div>
        )
    }
}
```

child class :

```
import GFormEdit from './GFormEdit'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

export default class TrivPw extends GFormEdit {
    render() {
        return (
            <Button variant='primary' onClick={() => this.showModalList()}>Clik Me !!!</Button>
        )
    }
}
```

this code is running well. When i click button in TrivPw.jsx the console shows 'show modal list runs'. I need to know whether i doing is right or wrong. Is there any better way? Please give me advice

I need to know about inheritance in React JS

Comment: There’s no “right or wrong”, there’s “what makes sense in context”. It **may** make sense to have component subclasses under some circumstances. It can also lead to problems later when it stops making sense.